# How active button using java script or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have virtual keyboard.
I want active button when any key pressed.
I used CSS active class. It works. But it only work when I press button by mouse.
If I press button from key board it not work.
Here is my CSS

```
#keyboard li:active {
    position: relative;
    top: 1px;
    left: 1px;
    background-color: #e74c3c;
    border-color: #e5e5e5;
    cursor: pointer;
    color:white;
}
```

This is the link
http://projects.imube.com/keyboard/

Comment: Can you provide a working snippet for the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var hey = document.getElementById('hey');

let makeActive = () => {
  hey.classList.contains('active') ? hey.classList.remove('active') : hey.classList.add('active');
}

hey.onclick = makeActive;

window.onkeypress = (e) => {
  let key = e.keyCode || e.which;

  if(e.keyCode == 13) {
    makeActive();  
  }
}
```

```css
a.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<a id="hey">Press Enter or Click this!</a>
```

You need two different event handlers. One is keypress and click.

Here's you can get keyCode: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/javascript-keycodes/

Hope it helps.

Comment: The OP has used jQuery, so it would be easier if you add a class `key` and the `keyCode` as id to every button. So you can just do `$('.key').removeClass('active'); $('#' + e.keyCode).addClass('active');` whenever there is a keyPress

Comment: The OP said javascript or jQuery. I favored javascript because of fast rendering.